# O(log(A+B)) = O(log(A*B))?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

As in the title, is this equation true?

```
O(log(A+B)) = O(log(A*B))
```

Both functions are more or less similar (neither one grows significantly faster than the other) so I guess we could write sth like:

```
O(log(A+B)) ≈ O(log(A*B))
```

But for it to be exactly equal don't both functions need to have the exact same asymptotic growth?

Comment: I think that depends on the values of A and B. For example if A = B, then you have O(log(A+A)) = (O(log(A\*A)), where A*A = A^2. So I think that's not true, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @beeef: log(A^2) = 2*log(A).

Comment: uh sorry.. too long ago. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are indeed right. This is because we have the following inequalities (for large enough A and B):

```
log(A+B) ≤ log(A*B)
```

and

```
log(A*B) = log(A) + log(B) ≤ log(A + B) + log(A + B) = 2 * log(A + B)
```

#### Remark:

Using the big-O notation is not precisely correct here, you are dealing with the tight bound between `log(A+B)` and `log(A*B)`, so you should use the big-Theta notation:

```
log(A + B) = Θ(log(A * B))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a ratio of them

```
r = log(A + B) / log(A * B) = log(A + B) / (log(A) + log(B))
```

If both A and B approach infinity, this expression has a finite positive limit:

1) If A/B < 1 then

```
log(A)/(2 * log(A)) <  r < (log(A) + log(2)) / log(A)
1/2 < r < 1 + log(2)/log(A)
```

2) Substitute A with B for B/A < 1

3) A == B is trivial

So the complexities are the same.